# Draw rectangle from coordinates

Tags: ios, qr-code, avcapturesession

I am writing a QR code recognizer in iOS 7. I have a captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: delegate for my camera view capture. Once a QR code is recognized, I can extract the coordinates of corners. I am trying to draw a rectangle around the recognized QR code. It is surprisingly hard to do. What would be the easiest way to go? I will have to have a method to update the path of the box around the QR code.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    if ([metadataObjects count] < 1) {
        return;
    }
    for (id item in metadataObjects) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject class]]) {
            if (item) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [item stringValue]);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self drawRect:[item corners]];
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the question is how do I implement drawRect: to draw a rectangle around a recognized QR code?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the four points from the points property of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject to draw a CGBezierPath in your view or in a custom overlay view.

Comment: Can you hit as to how to update/hide it when there is no metadataObject detected?

Comment: Check if you captured anything. If so, loop through them and draw them. You might find it easy to add some BOOL or NSUInteger value to check in drawRect: